# How to optimize posts query in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, query-optimization

basically, I'm trying to optimize this query we have more than 100K blogs and I need to make it faster now it takes Load time **(07.46 s)**.

```
<?php
                    if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ); }
                    elseif ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'page' ); }
                    else { $paged = 1; }
                            $query = new WP_Query(array(
                                'date_query' => array(
                                        array(
                                                'year' => date( 'Y' )-2,
                                                'compare'   => '>=',
                                        ),
                                ),
                                'posts_per_page'   => 10,
                                'paged' => $paged
                            ));
                            while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); ?>
                    <article id="post-<?php the_id() ?>" class="card bg-light text-dark card-blog">

                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('large',['class'=>'card-img-top']); ?>

                        <div class="card-body">
                            <span class="card-meta">
                                <time datetime="<?php echo strtotime(the_time('F j, Y')); ?>"><?php echo the_time('F j, Y'); ?></time> | <?php the_category(', '); ?>
                            </span>
                            <h3 class="card-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                            <p class="lead"><?php  echo substr(get_the_excerpt(),0,50).'...'; ?></p>
                            <div class="btn-container">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More<?php gpi_sprite('arrow-right'); ?></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </div>
            </section>
                <?php
                    $pages = paginate_links( array(
                        'format' => '?page=%#%',
                        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('page') ),
                        'total' => $query->max_num_pages,
                        'type'=>'array',
                    ) );
                ?>
```

the above query grabbing all blog posts 10 posts per page but I show only the latest 2 years and this takes much expected than I imagine **I appreciate any help**

Comment: Please consider using the [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin. Please use it to find the SQL forthe offending query, then [edit] your question to show it to us.

Answer (score 0):

you can use these two keys before and after rather than Compare

```
'date_query' => array(
    'after' => '2021-06-01',
    'before' => '2023-06-01',
),
```

Comment: thanks for your response the same result, did not reflect anything.

Answer (score 0):

The `wp_posts` table has an index on `(post_type, post_status, post_date,ID)`. If you only query by date you can't exploit that index, and your query may have to look at the entire table (which is large in your case).

You might try querying for only published posts. What you call *blogs* are called posts in WordPress parlance. That may allow the MySQL database to exploit the index.  You could try this query (*not debugged*):

```php
    $query = new WP_Query(array(
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'date_query' => array(
         array(
           'year' => date( 'Y' )-2,
           'compare'   => '>=',
         ),
      ),
    'posts_per_page'   => 10,
    'paged' => $paged
   ));
```

It will be hard to help you further until you use the [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin to investigate the slow query.

Comment: thanks for your response the same result, did not reflect anything